# Bootstrap modal closes after clicking in Dropdown Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal, semantic-ui

I have implemented a dropdown semantic ui in a bootstrap modal but its somehow conflicting with the modal. It opens successfully however, as soon as I click in the dropdown, modal closes. The reason is because of the loaded CDN files, since modal's class name is "modal" which is the same as in the file loaded for the semantic dropdown.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet'>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.7/semantic.css">    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>       
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.7/semantic.js"></script
```

Above you can see all the loaded CDN.

Below is the modal (not posting all of it because its large):

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="my_modal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    ...
    <select class="ui fluid search dropdown" multiple="">
        <option value="">Skills</option>
        <option value="angular">Angular</option>
        <option value="css">CSS</option>
        <option value="design">Graphic Design</option>
        <option value="ember">Ember</option>
        <option value="html">HTML</option>
    </select>
 </div>
```

Running example: https://jsfiddle.net/burimsyla/2ws8yndm/9/

Comment: Why are you using jquery `1.9.0` and `3.4.1`. Also without seeing enough code to recreate the problem it's hard to help you.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I just removed the 1.9.0 but same problem

Comment: jQuery is not the problem here - Are you able to provide to minimal example of this where this problem can be seen - adding `data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"` should be enough - modal should not close at all unless clicked on the close `X` button

Comment: @AlwaysHelping there you go a jsfiddle running example https://jsfiddle.net/burimsyla/2ws8yndm/9/

Comment: Are you loading the modal on page load or on a click of a button in your real project ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping on click of a button. I added a button in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5xy3zj9L/1/

Comment: Are you really using an `onclick` function to open a bootstrap modal in your project ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I am in fact calling  a function onClick which makes an Ajax call and on success I open modal. Would that be a problem? It works perfectly fine without this dropdown

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it is very relevant :) trust me on that one - the way boostrap data-backdrop and static works.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping but that's not causing the issue in this case since it works fine without the dropdown. Eitherway, how else would you open a modal on success callback of an ajax call?

Comment: I have solution already :) but feel like should post only with an onclick function working - i am trying.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping thanks! Btw the data-backdrop is being ignored, I can still close it when clicking on background, strange :/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I am just confirming things to get a full background how the modal opens in the first place or was that just for jsfiddle example- THATS all :) It is definitely connected to the `onclick` function.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I am deeply sorry to you. if you feel it was not helpful by me just wanting to know full details.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping could you make it work?

Comment: @B.S. Not with an `onClick` function. the way you wanted. but the bootstrap way yes its works.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping ok just send a link, I will take a look

Comment: I would highly suggest if you could consider using `semantic UI` own [modal function](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/examples) instead of using `boostrap modal` - otherwise there is no way around it since `semantic` and `boostrap` is using same modal classes - thats what causing the issue of modal disappearing. Good luck :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221816/discussion-between-always-helping-and-b-s).

Comment: @B.S. yes I know I mentioned boostrap way solution - its possible but not using Ajax success or onclick - the bootstrap solution is to use data-target on a button to open a modal instead of using .modal(show) - data-target modal example can be found on bootstrap website. But I do not think that will meet you need since you want to open a modal Ajax success in which the data-target will not work. I tried every option using onclick but the semantic is causing issues. Thank you.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping no prob.

Comment: @B.S. Not sure if you found a perfect solution or not but i posted a working and efficient solution below just if someone is having this issue as well. Also, sorry it was too late last night could not focus enough to post an answer yesterday. Thanks for giving out all the details in comments to provide a proper solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `semantic UI` has it own `modal` as well and they share the same `classes` as `bootstrap` modal as discussed in the comment. Here is a most `simple` and right `approach` to tackle this issue nicely.

You can either you use `data-target` to open a modal which is a direct bootstrap way which does not involve any jQuery need as well.

```
<!-- Direct open -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modalAddNewAdmin" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAddNewAdmin">
  Open Modal Directly
</button>
```

But since in your `scenario` the modal must be open after the `ajax` is called successfully the `code` below will **not** work and will interfere with Semantic modal CSS.

```
$("#modalAddNewAdmin").modal('show'); //do not use this on success because of semantic UI
```

To **get around** this issue and most `efficiently` without doing any changes and alteration you can simulate / trigger a `click` on your `ajax` success you can use:

```
$(".modalAddNewAdmin").click(); //simulate /trigger a click function on success
```

This works the same way `.modal('show')` but the best part is its does interact with `semantic UI` at all and modal open and `dropdown` work perfectly.

You can check out `ajax` success working demo here on `JSfiddle` as well (Since ajax does not work on `stackoverflow` snippets): https://jsfiddle.net/xh8urkcf/

**Live working Demo:**

```js
//Semantic UI
$('.ui.fluid.dropdown').dropdown({});

//Ajax call
function myAjaxCall() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/', //simulates ajax call
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      //$("#modalAddNewAdmin").modal('show'); //do not use this because of semantic UI
      $(".modalAddNewAdmin").click(); //simulate a click function on success to open modal
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet'>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.7/semantic.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.7/semantic.css">

<!-- Direct open -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modalAddNewAdmin" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAddNewAdmin">
  Open Modal Directly
</button>

<!-- Via ajax -->
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="myAjaxCall()">Open Modal Via Ajax</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAddNewAdmin" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <select class="ui fluid search dropdown" multiple="true">
          <option value="">Skills</option>
          <option value="angular">Angular</option>
          <option value="css">CSS</option>
          <option value="design">Graphic Design</option>
          <option value="ember">Ember</option>
          <option value="html">HTML</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```